# @BeforeSuite not working

Tags: java, testng

I have tried this :
**BaseClass**

```
package pages;

import org.testng.annotations.BeforeSuite;

public class BaseClass {

    @BeforeSuite
    public static void setup() {
        System.out.println("in set up method");
    }

}
```

**TestClass**

```
 package pages;

 import org.testng.annotations.Test;

 public class TestClass extends BaseClass {

@Test(groups = { "group1" })

public void grpOnetest() {
    System.out.println("Method grp one");

}

@Test(groups = { "group2" })

public void grpTwotest() {
    System.out.println("Method grp two");

}

@Test(groups = { "group3" })

public void grpThreetest() {
    System.out.println("method grp three");

}
}
```

**testng.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite">

    <test name="Test">
        <groups>
            <run>
                <include name="group1" />
            </run>
        </groups>
        <classes>
            <class name="pages.TestClass" />
        </classes>
    </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

It doesnt give any error, just don't print:
"in set up method" i.e. doesn't run `@BeforeSuite`

Comment: Add `alwaysRun = true` on `@BeforeSuite` and/or remove `static`

Comment: Worked, whats the concept behind it, can you put it in an answer? Why we need `alwaysRun` (obviously because it is setup method) why it can't run without it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need `alwaysRun = true` on `@BeforeSuite`.

From [the documentation](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html):

> For before methods (beforeSuite, beforeTest, beforeTestClass and beforeTestMethod, but not beforeGroups): If set to true, this configuration method will be run regardless of what groups it belongs to.

In other words, if you run a suite with specific group(s), configuration methods must have the expected group(s) or have `alwaysRun` that will activate the method with every goups.

Comment: When i add alwaysRun=True, I am getting the error : The attribute alwaysRun is undefined for the annotation type BeforeSuit. Any insights?

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the setup method in the group that you are including, else it wouldn't run since that method is not part of the group.

Add the suite to all the groups, that should work.

Comment: If I am extending the baseclass ,then there is no need I think.

Comment: Nope, there is a need - try it. You might want to have specific setups per group and that's the reason.

Comment: I tried it is giving error: `The content of element type "groups" must match "(define*,run?,dependencies?)".`